# Trello shows me online when I just click on its tab (not bringing the mouse in)

Tags: trello

Isn't there anywhere an option to disable this behavior?

Even gmail doesn't activate your status (when you are idle) as soon as you just click on gmail tab!

It's a very bad behavior that trello shows everyone that you are online even when just you want to view the page!

Wish there was a solution for this terrible behavior of Trello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't see the issue here. If you open the tab, it should be assumed that you are active on it, even if it was for a second. If you don't want people to know you are on then don't open the tab yet.

Comment: But it's not the way that gmail.com behaves. Gmail shows your status active (green) ___only___ when the mouse comes ___into___ the page itself. When just clicking (so you are just viewing what's going on), you will still stay idle (yellow). OK, I think that you mean there is no way to change the behavior.

Comment: @MohammadNaji That is a different application. It is not possible in Trello.